# Inaccurate results from Lagrange Interpolation in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I have written a Fortran program to compute the Lagrange interpolation of two data sets: x,G. I am not able to evaluate the defined function correctly. Please see what I did wrong as while my program runs, the numbers are not at all accurate for the fxn see first two programs (Matlab code) to see actual result). They are provided by the author and are what I am trying to emulate on Fortran:

```
  %% example 1.1 langrange interpolation %(Matlab)

 % X : interpolation points
 % Y : value of f(X)
 % x : points where we want an evaluation of P(x),
 %     where P is the interpolator polynomial
x = [-1:0.01:1];
X = [-1:0.20:1];

y = 1./(1+25*x.^2);
Y = 1./(1+25*X.^2);
pol = lagrange_interp(X,Y,x)
%plot(x,pol,'k',x,y,'k--',X,Y,'k.');
legend('Lagrange Polynomial','Expected behavior','Data Points');


  function polynomial = lagrange_interp(X,Y,x) %(Matlab)


 n          = length(X);
 phi        = ones(n,length(x));
 polynomial = zeros(1,length(x));
 i = 0;
 j = 0;

 for i = [1:n]
    for j = [1:n]
       if not(i==j)
       phi(i,:) = phi(i,:).*(x-X(j))./(X(i)-X(j));
      end;
   end;
 end;

  for i = [1:n]
    polynomial = polynomial + Y(i)*phi(i,:);
  end;


!Lagrange Interpolation example !(Fortran)

 program Lagrange
  implicit none
integer:: i
integer, parameter:: n=10
integer, parameter:: z=201
integer, parameter:: z1=11
real, parameter:: delta=.01
real,parameter:: delta2=.20
real, dimension(1:z):: x,G,y,H
real*8, dimension(1:n):: M
real*8, dimension(1:n):: linterp(n)
x(1)=-1
 G(1)=-1

   do i=2,z
   x(i)=x(i-1)+delta
     y(i)=1/(1+25*(x(i)**2))

 end do

  print*, "The one-dimensional array x is:", x(1:z)
  print*, "The one dimensional array y is", y(1:z)

  do i=2,z1
G(i)=G(i-1)+delta2
H(i)=1/(1+25*(G(i)**2))

 end do
  print*,"The other one-dimensional array G is:", G(1:z1)
  print*, "Then the one dimensional array H is", H(1:z1)

  M=linterp(1:n)
  print*, M(1:n)
 end program

 !Lagrange interpolation polynomial function !(Fortran)

  real*8 function linterp(n)
  implicit none
 integer,parameter:: n=10
 integer, dimension(1:n):: poly,pol
  integer:: i, j
  i=0
  j=0
  do i=1,n
     do j=1,n
    if (i/=j)then
        poly(i,j)=poly(i,j)*(x(i)-G(j))/(y(i)-G(j))
    end if
end do
end do
print*, poly(i,j)
  do i=1,n
    pol(i)=pol(i)+H(i)*poly(i,j)
   end do
   print*, pol(1:n)
    end function
```

Comment: What does it mean they are not accurate? How do the results look like? How should they look like instead?

Comment: If  you present your code to other people (and even if not) please use consistent indentation in your code. It is very hard to see the structure of your code.

Comment: Heaps of problems here. You have several uninitialised variables/arrays, e.g. `pol` and `poly`. Why are you passing `n` as an argument to `linterp` but making it a parameter inside the function? You are referencing `j` in the last loop outside any loop with `j` as a counter. There are several scoping errors etc, etc.  I refuse to believe that this code even compiles!

Comment: Indeed, `real*8 function linterp(n);  integer,parameter:: n=10` should definitely not compile.

Comment: I am quite new to Fortran as you must guess but was trying to directly use the above Matlab programs. If you look at the Matlab script,    pol and poly are two different quantities to be used (which is why I reference j in the latter loop of the fortran function) ; one is 2d array, the other is 1d. Being said, how would I be able to run this function within my main program? How would you all rewrite this code to properly use the function to generate both "pol" and "poly"?The Matlab code above is working and gives the results I wish to emulate on Fortran if you need a reference. Thanks

Comment: For a first cut you could take that Matlab code and re-write it into Fortran line-by-line, making the (generally) minor adjustments necessary to conform to Fortran's syntax; for example translate `x = [-1:0.01:1]` into something like `x = [w,w=-1,0.01,1)]` and so on.  Crikey, you don't even need to declare variables in Fortran if you don't want to.  But the Fortran you show us is sufficiently different from the Matlab (e.g. the Matlab version of `lagrange_interp` takes 3 arguments, the Fortran version only 1) that I think you are trying to do too much in one step.  KISS

Comment: So lets say I split the fortran fxn file into two function files where "linterp(n)" is responsible for generating "poly" and a new fxn file "polly(n)" is responsible for generating "pol". When I do define these into separate functions, and call them into the main program I get an error: "undefined reference to linterp/polly". What does this mean as I have explcitly defined both as external variables in the main program?